# Modal popup with partialview

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a partial view in a modal popup
I have added the following scripts on my main view

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  $('.details_display').on('click', function () {
      $(".budgetdetail").dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          position: { my: "center", at: "top+350", of: window },
          width: 1000,
          resizable: false,
          title: 'Detail',
          modal: true,
          open: function () {
              $(this).load('@Url.Action("DisplayBudgetDetail", "Budget")');
          }
      });

  });
  });
 </script>
```

and also this division

```
</div>
```

The Link to call the popup looks like this:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Detail", "DBudgetDetail", new { id = item.idBudget }, new { @class = "details_display" })
```

However when I click on it I am redirected to a new page with the view I am trying to display and no popup is being created.

I am getting this error when I debug my java script

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
$(".budgetdetail").dialog({
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be with your script files

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

**1. You appear to be including JQuery and JQueryUI twice**

You either need to use the bundles (`"~/bundles/jquery"` & `"~/bundles/jqueryui"`) or the script tags. Do not use both.

**2. The scripts are in the wrong order**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

The browser will execute the script in the order you include them. You have JQuery UI included first and then JQuery. These need to be the other way around. JQuery UI requires JQuery to work.